# cakephp 3.* installation issue

Tags: php, cakephp, installation, composer-php

Cakephp is my first PHP framework. I followed the instructions in Documentation / install. It seems everything was correct, but when i tried to run, i get errors:

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/caketest/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/caketest/config/bootstrap.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/caketest/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/caketest/config/bootstrap.php on line 23

im using ubuntu with php 5.5.9, pear is installed

I tried to find the solution but without sucsess. 
How to correct these errors?

Comment: Have you followed the guide of installing cakephp3? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp. This error means that CakePHP can't find the autoload file which is produced from composer.

Comment: Thank you for Your comment! Helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there was a missing package in my system. - **php5-intl**

It was written in official CakePHP install manual, and i checked it but looks like not well.

Install manual for **php5-intl**

http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

ps: restart apache after instalation

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: If you installed cakephp through composer I can't understand how the composer installed it without the php5-intl inside your system. It should break and not install the framework. Anyway glad you found the solution

Comment: The files were there, but some missing.