# Cakephp installation error by command php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app [app_name]

Tags: php, cakephp

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\vendor\autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\vendor\autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 23

Comment: Please show the whole output of `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app` - if the autoload.php file isn't created (a fundamental file used by composer) the installation was incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

This means that it can't find the autoload file produced by composer. Maybe composer could not complete the whole procedure because a package is missing. 
Check this question too.

[cakephp 3.* installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353402/cakephp-3-installation-issue#comment52581193_32353402)